# openssl pkcs12 -export : unable to load private key

Tags: openssl, certificate, codesign

I'm trying to convert a .cer certificate (from Sectigo) to a .pfx, to use with an Electron App.

i'm using this command line :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey votre_clef_privee.key -in resultat.pem -name mon_nom -out resultat_final.pfx
```

I've got this error :
unable to load Private Key
4540540588:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong

My key is with this format :

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIEyTXXX...
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

What could be the problem ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: **That file is not a key** and specifically not a private key which is what `pkcs12 -inkey` requires. As the PEM labels say, it is a "CERTIFICATE REQUEST" -- also called a Certificate Signing Request, abbreviated CSR. For most certs (like SSL/TLS and email) usually the private key and CSR are created at the same _time_ and you're supposed to save both; perhaps you didn't follow the instructions correctly. But some codesigning cert programs make this more difficult or even impossible. And this isn't programming or development.